# Dynamic show and hide fields in Django admin panel

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have defined model in which one of the filed has definition:

```
REPEAT = (
    ('day', 'Daily'),
    ('week', 'Weekly'),
)

repeats = models.CharField('Repeat', default='day', max_length=5, choices=REPEAT)
```

Also I have defined related admin model, which is responsible to show my main model in panel.

Is possible to show and hide some fields in admin panel based on choice in *repeats* field? For example in scenery when user choose 'Daily', then some fields are not required and I want to hide them.
I will be thankful for any advices or hints.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can add custom JS to your admin model:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    class Media:
        js = ("my_code.js",)
```

STATIC_URL is appended to your filename automagically.

And your JS function, assuming jQuery, something like:

```
$(function(){
$('<my-selector>').change(function(){
    //do something on select change
    });
});
```