# Django Admin Show / Hide Fields If Specific Value Is Selected In A Dropdown

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-admin

In the Django admin, when the choice `Custom` is selected from a dropdown list, I want to display the inline `start_date` and `end_date` fields to allow the user to specify a specific start and end-date instead of a pre-defined time period.

After researching for some time, suggestions include: use hidden fields, define override get_form in ModelAdmin, or use custom Javascript (which I have zero experience with).

**The Question**: how can I display (show) the inline `start_date` and `end_date` fields when a specific value (`Custom`) is selected in the dropdown of a Django Admin field? When `Custom` is not selected, `start_date` and `end_date` would be hidden from view.

---

**Step 1:**
[image: step 1 - select a date range]

**Step 2:**
[image: step 2 - if custom is selected]

**Step 3:**
[image: step 3 - show the inline custom date fields]

---

Below is a complete example of the exact example code I have locally:

**settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    ...
    'dropdown.apps.DropdownConfig',
]
```

**apps.py**

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class DropdownConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'dropdown'
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class DropdownModel(models.Model):

    CHOICES = (
        ('Today', 'Today'),
        ('Yesterday', 'Yesterday'),
        ('Last 7 Days', 'Last 7 Days'),
        ('Last 14 Days', 'Last 14 Days'),
        ('Last 30 Days', 'Last 30 Days'),
        ('Last 60 Days', 'Last 60 Days'),
        ('Last 90 Days', 'Last 90 Days'),
        ('This Year', 'This Year'),
        ('All Time', 'All Time'),
        ('Custom', 'Custom')
    )

    date_range = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    start_date = models.DateField()
    end_date = models.DateField()
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from dropdown.models import DropdownModel

class DropdownModelForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = DropdownModel
        fields = ('date_range',)
        widgets = {
            'date_range': forms.Select(choices=DropdownModel.CHOICES)
        }
```

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from dropdown.models import DropdownModel
from dropdown.forms import DropdownModelForm

class DropdownModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = (
        ('Date Range', {
            'fields': ('date_range', ('start_date', 'end_date'))
        }),
    )
    form = DropdownModelForm

admin.site.register(DropdownModel, DropdownModelAdmin)
```

Comment: I don't think you will run away from having a custom JS.... take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18678711/dynamic-show-and-hide-fields-in-django-admin-panel

Comment: Well, if your goal is to hide and show in live time, Javascript (AJAX) is not an option, it is in fact mandatory. I don't see any way with built-in Django features for you to acheive that.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Purpose of this question**: to show / hide a fieldset if a specific option is selected in a Django admin form dropdown.

**Solution overview**: you need to break fieldsets up into two instead of one, custom javascript, define `Media` class in ModelAdmin.

**[Step One]** In my project named `dropdown`, I added the following folders / files:

- static (directory)
- static/dropdown (directory)
- static/dropdown/js (directory)
- static/dropdown/js/base.js (file)

**[Step Two]** In admin.py, a few things to note:

1. I broke `fieldsets` up into two instead of one.
2. Notice that I'm defining `classes` for each fieldset. `abcdefg` is the name of the class of the fieldset I'm trying to show and hide.
3. I defined `class Media`. This tells django where to look for custom javascript and css files.

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from dropdown.models import DropdownModel
from dropdown.forms import DropdownModelForm

class DropdownModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    fieldsets = (
        ('Date Range', {
            'fields': ('date_range',),
            'classes': ('predefined',)
        }),
        (None, {
            'fields': (('start_date', 'end_date'),),
            'classes': ('abcdefg',)
        })
    )

    form = DropdownModelForm

    class Media:
        js = ('dropdown/js/base.js',)

admin.site.register(DropdownModel, DropdownModelAdmin)
```

**[Step Three]** Add javascript.
I take no credit for this script; I only modified it slightly from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26139206/django-admin-hide-field-on-change-select-field).

**base.js**

```
(function($) {
    $(function() {
        var selectField = $('#id_date_range'),
            verified = $('.abcdefg');

        function toggleVerified(value) {
            if (value === 'Custom') {
                verified.show();
            } else {
                verified.hide();
            }
        }

        // show/hide on load based on existing value of selectField
        toggleVerified(selectField.val());

        // show/hide on change
        selectField.change(function() {
            toggleVerified($(this).val());
        });
    });
})(django.jQuery);
```

**[Step Four]**

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from dropdown.models import DropdownModel

class DropdownModelForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = DropdownModel
        fields = ('date_range',)
        widgets = {
            'date_range': forms.Select(choices=DropdownModel.CHOICES)
        }
```

Comment: Just used this solution! Works like a charm :-)

Comment: where do you get the id to fill var selectField = $('#id_date_range') ? is id_date_range the html id of the date range field?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Each form field has an ID attribute set to id_<field-name>.

Comment: Is it possible to use your approach in a StackedInline class? I'm trying to do exactly the same, but in a tab of my admin page. I had no success so far. It seems that the Javascript isn't detecting my fieldsets classes, hence not showing or hiding conditionally.

Comment: SOLVED MY ISSUE: My django project wasn't loading static file "base.js" correctly... the solution works like a charm with inlines!

Comment: @Twimnox how have you solved the loading of static file?