# Conditional field rendering django admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I am new to Django. I would like to show some fields in the Django Admin only if a specific value has been selected on a dropdown.

For instance, I have a question model. I would like to let the user select the type of question. If it is a multiple choice question, I would like to show fields to let the user fill the possible answers.

I have found this [link](https://www.fusionbox.com/blog/detail/creating-conditionally-required-fields-in-django-forms/577/) but it seems that it is not done for the Django Admin.

How should I proceed to achieve what I need ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django Admin Show / Hide Fields If Specific Value Is Selected In A Dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47838059/django-admin-show-hide-fields-if-specific-value-is-selected-in-a-dropdown)

Answer (score 0):

If the object already exists (meaning it's not a creation form) I think this could help you: [ModelAdmin.get_fields()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_fields).